# How to convert comma separated numbers to integer mysql query GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

I have a comma separated numbers like **'46,95,44'** which is the output obtained from GROUP_CONCAT

```
select GROUP_CONCAT (prodid) from tablename where condition;
```

I want to convert this to integer such that i can use this as the input to the "in" operation

```
select * from table2 where prodid in 
(
   select GROUP_CONCAT (prodid) from tablename where condition
);
```

The above query results only base on the first number in the comma separated list . How to convert the list in to integer

```
output :  46,95,44
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `group_concat`

```
select * from table2 
where prodid in 
(
  select prodid
  from tablename
  where condition
);
```

`group_concat` produces a **single** string with ids, but you need **seperate** values for the `IN` clause.

With `group_concat` your query compiles to

```
select * from table2 
where prodid in ('46,95,44');
```

but you need

```
select * from table2 
where prodid in ('46','95','44');
```

Comment: if the "select prodid
  from tablename
  where condition" returns multiple rows it will pop an error.

Comment: Then the error comes from something else. `IN` has no problem with multiple records. What is the complete error message?

Comment: @juergend your solution is perfect no doubt, but query taking too much of time

Comment: @Kuldeep: Then you can ask a question on Stack Overflow about it including table definition, example data, the query you tried and indexes you have on your tables.